Remove internal lines within merged polygon
I am having trouble removing internal lines from within a polygon. I have tried to dissolve, and to use the GRASS clean tool, but the data source has some inherent errors so it doesn't work. Any ideas?
UPDATE: when zooming in to a scale of 116:1, it looks like there are very small gaps between some areas of the polygon (0.00m)... So giving it a buffer of 0.001m solved the aesthetic issue - but is there a better way to do it without having to buffer?



Possible to use the difference tool?

@Nubtacular gave it a shot and same result - still has all the internal lines.

Try Delete Holes

Takes a polygon layer and removes holes in polygons. It creates a new
vector layer in which polygons with holes have been replaced by
polygons with only their external ring

Set an area threshold, if you have holes you want to keep.

